# Is this a correct use of do check in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to call a service to post data, for every time the user changes any dropdown values (there are severals dropdowns in the component) or user types inside an input (eg: name) like this:

```
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="clientName">           

  <select [(ngModel)]="selectTop">
  <option *ngFor="let top of TypesTops" [value]="top.TypeTopId"> {{top.TypeTopName}}
  </option>
  </select>
```

In the component i use the ngDoCheck function, so everytime a value changes a call to the service happens:

```
  ngDoCheck(): void {        
            let filter = this.getFilter();
            this.filterService.sendFilter(filter);           
    }
```

Also I have an input that I need to trigger the same call. Is this a correct approach of doing this ? Are there any setbacks on using ngDoCheck like in the example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should definitely check if the value actually changed in `ngDoCheck()` before sending the request.

`ngDoCheck()` is called every time change detection is run, which can be quite often.

I think a better way for your use case is to use an event that fires when the select changes

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectTop" (ngModelChange)="selectChanged()">
```

```
selectChanged(): void {        
        let filter = this.getFilter();
        this.filterService.sendFilter(filter);           
}
```